# Giving an attribute to an xmlhttprequest object

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code :

```
<head>
<script>

function startChanging() {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

    for(var i=0; i < elems.length; i++)
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp["elem"] = elems[i];
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                this["elem"].src = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://myurl.com/somescript.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

};

</script>
</head>

<body onload="startChanging()">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
<br/>
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
<br/>
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
</body>
```

Even though I create a new instance of `XMLHttpRequest` for each iteration and add the current element to an attribute, when the request returns a response only the last `img` element is changed.

I am looking for a simple solution to change the `src` of the `img` element without iterating through all the elements again when the response comes. I would like a pure Javascript solution (read: no JQuery).

I am certainly doing something wrong here I just don't understand what. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why don't you use jquery

Comment: I'm testing this with the purpose to later be injected into http traffic via squid. At that point I don't know what browser the user has or even if it supports JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `for` loop, you are overwriting the `xmlhttp` variable so when you get into the `onreadystatechage` function and you check the value of `xmlhttp.readyState`, it will not be checking the right object.

I'd suggest this fix which changes two things:

1. It puts each ajax call into it's own IIFE which keeps the `xmlhttp` variable separate for each ajax call.
2. It passes `elems[i]` into the closure so you don't have to do the property saving hack.

Code:

```
function startChanging() {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

    for(var i=0; i < elems.length; i++)
    {
        (function(obj) {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    obj.src = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://myurl.com/somescript.php", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        })(elems[i]);
    }

};
```

Comment: @Sebastian-LaurenţiuPlesciuc - I added a code solution.

Comment: Your solution looks better. Thank you.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I've suggested how the OP can fix their problem and clean up their code a bit.

Comment: Why won't it be checking the right object? The handler should be attached to the object which is referred to as `xmlhttp` at the time it's added? Edit: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: @Basic - inside the `readystatechange` function which is called sometime LATER, the value of `xmlhttp` in the OP's code would be the last `xmlhttp` object they created, not necessarily the one that generated the `onreadystatechange` event.  Thus, they would be checking the `readyState` on the wrong `xmlhttp` object.  Remember, the ajax response is asynchronous.  It completes sometime later AFTER the `for` loop has run to completion and `xmlhttp` will contain the value of the last `XMLHttpRequest()` object the `for` loop created, not necessarily the one that generated the event.

Comment: +1 from me as well, closuring over `obj` here is a better choice indeed.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    this.elem.src = this.responseText;
  }
}
```

As you see, I've replaced all the references to `xmlhttp` within that handler function to `this`.

The problem is even though you've created a new AJAX-serving object at each step of the loop, each newly-created `'readystatechange'` handler function referred to the same object known under `xmlhttp` variable.

In general, this is quite a common problem when someone works with a variable declared within a loop yet referred by functions created in the same loop. Stumble upon this once or twice, and you'll begin to see the pattern. )

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlhttp.send();
```

Put data into the send method:

```
xmlhttp.send(data);
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

```
void send();
void send(ArrayBuffer data);
void send(ArrayBufferView data);
void send(Blob data);
void send(Document data);
void send(DOMString? data);
void send(FormData data);
```

Where `data` is a JavaScript variable, you can put anything into. If you want multipart message, you'd use `var data = new FormData();` and put data into it using `data.append('image', file);` for file upload via ajax for example.
If no multipart, simply put anything in like:

```
data = { images: document.getElementsByTagName("img") }
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly how I would use `data`. Wouldn't it create a copy of the element that is not the same element from the DOM?